# Texlipse can't find font files

Tags: luatex

i have a LuaLaTeX document which should use some fonts but i get some errors which says that the font files can't be found. The fonts are in a subdirectory of the project. In the "Project Explorer" are the fonts folder and the LuaTeX file direct childs of the project. My code to include the fonts are:

```
\setsansfont[Path=fonts/,BoldFont={FiraSans-Regular.ttf}]{FiraSans-Light.ttf}
\setmonofont[Path=fonts/]{FiraMono-Regular.ttf}
\newfontfamily\ExtraLight[Path=fonts/,ItalicFont=FiraSans-ExtraLightItalic.ttf]{FiraSans-ExtraLight.ttf}
\newfontfamily\Light[Path=fonts/,ItalicFont=FiraSans-LightItalic.ttf]{FiraSans-Light.ttf}
\newfontfamily\Book[Path=fonts/,ItalicFont=FiraSans-Italic.ttf,BoldFont=FiraSans-Bold.ttf,BoldItalicFont=FiraSans-BoldItalic.ttf]{FiraSans-Regular.ttf}
\newfontfamily\Medium[Path=fonts/,ItalicFont=FiraSans-MediumItalic.ttf]{FiraSans-Medium.ttf}
```

and this is one of the errors:

```
lualatex.exe> !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
lualatex.exe> !
lualatex.exe> ! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
lualatex.exe> ! 
lualatex.exe> ! The font "FiraSans-Light.ttf" cannot be found.
lualatex.exe> ! 
lualatex.exe> ! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
lualatex.exe> ! 
lualatex.exe> ! For immediate help type H <return>.
lualatex.exe> !...............................................  
lualatex.exe>                                                   
lualatex.exe> l.18 ...FiraSans-Regular.ttf}]{FiraSans-Light.ttf}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Removing Eclipse from consideration for the moment, does the document work when you compile at the command line in the project folder?

Comment: @MikeRenfro No, when i compile it in the console i become the same errors.

Comment: Ok. Not that I can help with it right now, but at least we know it's not related to Eclipse. Edited tags accordingly.

Comment: You'll also get better results if you can prune your document down to the smallest [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that shows the error. In the process of creating the MWE, you might even identify your own solution.

Comment: Could it be that the relative path name of the subdirectory where the fonts are located is not named "fonts/"?